# Does Jenkins generic webhook option filtering actually prevent the build if it doesn't match

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline whos job is to take attached submodules, bundle them up in a zip, and push them to an artifact repo only on a merge to the primary branch; all of this logic works fine.

However, because a merge event gets trigged for `opened` and `merged` for merge requests, for every merge into the primary branch there is always an effective "no op" build because it will receive the `opened` event.

From the documentation around option filtering in the generic webhook, it isn't clear to me if a no-match also won't trigger a build, or simply will product a value of `""`. Here is the documentation:

```
Value filter
Optional. Anything in the evaluated value, matching this regular expression, will be removed. Having [^0-9] would only allow numbers. The regexp syntax is documented here.
```

This simply leads to the javadoc on regex.

I would love to not trigger a build at all, even a no-op build, unless the state is `"merged"`
[image: jenkins config]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it, but you need to add **Optional Filter** in another way.
In the end of GWT plugin configuration of your job, there is a global **Optional Filter** section:

[image]

Comment: hallelujah! It works!

Comment: Care to comment on this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75264454/does-jenkins-generic-webhook-option-filtering-on-multiple-variables